# Specifying multiple goals in Maven and running them separately

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I have created a testing framework using Cucumber, Selenium and Maven. I am using the `cucumber-jvm-parallel` plugin to run my tests in parallel. Below is how my `pom.xml` looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<name>Test Project</name>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.3</cucumber.version>
    <extentreports.version>2.41.0</extentreports.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.1</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>2.1.0</cucumber.jvm.parallel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sitture</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-extentreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>win</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>${basedir}${file.separator}resources${file.separator}chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>!windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webdriver.chrome.path>resources${file.separator}chromedriver</webdriver.chrome.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.parallel.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                        <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <format>json,html,rerun</format>
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                        <glue>com.cucumber.stepdefinitions</glue>
                        <tags>"~@ignore"</tags>
                        <filterFeaturesByTags>true</filterFeaturesByTags>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <!-- Increase Fork Count to increase parallel execution count.
                Currently it is set to 2 which means 2 runners will run in parallel-->
                <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>perform</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFileName>${basedir}${file.separator}pom.xml</pomFileName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I use

```
mvn clean install
```

to run my suite. After the run is complete, I have a downstream job configured in Jenkins that generates some failed cases file. I create separate runners for these. Now I was looking to rerun failed test cases and I have created files called `failedScenario1.java`, `failedScenario2.java` and so on. I would now like to run these. I am assuming I need to define something similar to `org.apache.maven.plugins` in the above POM and trigger the run. Can someone please let me know how I can include this in the same POM. Also how can I trigger this run for `failedScenario*.java`.

Comment: This doesn't address your question but is the use of version 3.1 of [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-compiler-plugin%22) intentional? This is almost 5 yrs old. [`maven-release-plugin:2.2.1`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-release-plugin%22) is even older.

Comment: Do I get this right: You're thinking of creating new Maven projects (new POMs, `pom.xml`s) on the fly, with `failedScenario*.java` as test sources and then building these including the `test` phase?

Comment: No. Actually I was thinking if I could specify a profile or goal in the same pom that would run only failedscenarios*.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible exactly as you like within the same POM.

You would need something like the following:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>suite</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>re-test</name>
          <value>!true</value>
        </property>
      <activation>

      ... your suite's declarations ...

    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>failed-scenario</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>re-test</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      <activation>
      <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>failed-scenario-test-compile</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            ...
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             ...
```

But, see [Introduction to Build Profiles, Profiles in POMs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Profiles_in_POMs):

> Profiles specified in the POM can modify the following POM elements:
>
> - ...
> - a subset of the `<build>` element, which consists of:
>
>   • `<defaultGoal>`
>
>   • `<resources>`
>
>   • `<testResources>`
>
>   • `<finalName>`

So, `<testSourceDirectory>` is missing there.

If you'd `generate-test-sources` to the default `<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java` you could use the `maven-surefire-plugin`'s `<excludes>/<includes>` in the `re-test` profile. The drawback is that all the `failedScenarioX` will be also run the next time you build your suite, unless you delete them before.

Comment: I referred your answer and came up with a solution on similar lines. I am creating a profile called Failed-Cases for running failed tests and using clean install -PFailed-Cases to run the failed scenarios. after the run is complete I am deleting the runner files. This works well however, it seems more like a hot fix than permanent solution. Any other ideas of implementing this?

Comment: @BountyHunter Re "_more like a hot fix_": This is not an usual scenario from Maven's point of view anyway. Normally it is one project, one test (suite), one set of test results that reflects all the tests of the entire project. The only other idea I have atm is to transfer the `failedScenarioX`s to a separate project with the original project being one of  its dependencies.